# accessing a method from a property and not an instance? Xcode

Tags: ios, swift

I'm confused how the following code uses the `view` property to access the subView method in the `viewDidLoad()` function. The `viewDidLoad` function provides access to the `view` property, but why is the `addSubView` method accessed from a property and not an instance?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 16, y: 16, width: 200,
height: 44))
    view.addSubview(label) // Adds label as a child view to `view`
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The view is a property of the viewcontroller, but it is an instance of UIView, which has a set of subviews, and you can add to this set by calling addSubview() on any UIView instance.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview

Answer (score 1):

A `UIViewController` has a property `view`. In swift, you can usually skip the "self" prefix when referring to properties of the current object.

The line `view.addSubview(label)` is equivalent to:

```
self.view.addSubview(label)
```

Or, to make it even clearer what it's doing by using a local variable:

```
let aView = self.view
aView.addSubview(label)
```